# Angular app http call custom service failing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm making a little angular app to show info about the english premier league. I want to make a service to deal with making http calls cos I do it a few times on the page and I don't want to repeat everything. Here is my table.js TableController, which is used for building a league table/

```
(function(){

angular
.module("eplApp")
.controller("tableCtrl", TableController);

TableController.inject = ['httpService'];

function TableController(service){
  var apiUrl = "http://api.football-data.org/v1/soccerseasons/426/leagueTable";

  service.getListFromUrl(apiUrl).then(function(data){
var vm.this;
vm.data = response.data;
});
}
})();
```

And here is the service I've made to run the http requests, service.js:

```
(function(){

angular
.module("eplApp")
.factory("httpService", httpService);

httpService.inject = ['$http'];

function httpService($http){
var apiKey = '971acba677654cdb919a7ccebd5621e2';
var vm = this;
vm.data = [];

$http({
  headers: { 'X-Auth-Token': apiKey },
  method: "GET",
  url: apiUrl
}).then(function(response) {
  vm.data = response.data;
  return vm.data;
});
}
})();
```

When I run it I get the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=serviceProvider%20%3C-%20service%20%3C-%20tableCtrl
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: I think you should start by injecting your service by name ('httpService') and not by its function name (HttpService)

Comment: Thanks @e-shfiyut. I've made the change you suggested but the error remains. I've changed the code above to reflect the changes.

Comment: you should read about how to create a factory/service in angular. factory is supposed to return an object, it is not just a function pointer. look at @Tan-Le 's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with change your service like that:

```
(function(){

    angular
    .module("eplApp")
    .factory("httpService", httpService);

    httpService.$inject = ['$http'];

    function httpService($http){
     return {
       getListFromURL : getListFromURL
     }

     function getListFromURL(apiUrl){
      var apiKey = '971acba677654cdb919a7ccebd5621e2';
      var vm = this;
      vm.data = [];

      return $http({
       headers: { 'X-Auth-Token': apiKey },
       method: "GET",
       url: apiUrl
      }).then(function(response) {
        vm.data = response.data;
        return vm.data;
      });
    }
})();
```

And call the function in controller like this:

```
TableController.$inject = ['httpService'];

function TableController(service){
  var apiUrl = "http://api.footballdata.org/v1/soccerseasons/426/leagueTable";

  service.getListFromURL(apiUrl).then(function(data){
    //data here is vm.data
  });
}
```

Hope this help !

Comment: Just a little comment about conventions (to the guy who asked this also), factory name should be camelCase: `httpService` and not `HttpService`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @TanLe, however i'm still getting the same error, in a different place this time. I've updated my question to reflect the code as you suggested and the error that I got from it.

Comment: Try to change `inject` to `$inject`. Look like wrong in that, so the `httpService` can not be injected into controller and make the error.

Comment: Thanks that seems to have worked for the problem I was having so I'll mark this as the answer. However I'm not not sure how I can get the data returned back into my view. I can only access that data within the service.getUrlFromList(apiUrl).then(function(data){ }) function.

Comment: You can assign data in function to $scope variable and can binding in view. You can view the document for binding data in angularjs in [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope). Note that you need inject `$scope` into controller to use.

Answer (score 3):

Check the controller you used, the controller function paramater is httpService, and you used inside is HttpService. Please chaeck that, Its case sensitive.

Comment: You're absolutely right, thanks for pointing that out. However I am still getting the same error. I've changed the code above to reflect the changes.